# How to use custom fonts in Android Studio

Tags: android, fonts

I am attempting to use a custom font in an Android app. I placed my font files under /app/src/main/assets/fonts, and I reference them with

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), 
"fonts/magorian_font.ttf")
```

When I run my app, I get the error:

```
04-23 16:14:40.017 13342-13342/com.pottermore.mandrake.pottermoreapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.pottermore.mandrake.pottermoreapp, PID: 13342
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pottermore.mandrake.pottermoreapp/com.pottermore.mandrake.pottermoreapp.ActivityHome}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found magorian_font.ttf
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found magorian_font.ttf
                                                                                       at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:206)
                                                                                       at com.pottermore.mandrake.pottermoreapp.ActivityHome.onCreate(ActivityHome.java:34)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the filename correct? If you use Build > Analyze APK in Android Studio, and open up your APK file, do you see your font in `assets/fonts/`?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found magorian_font.ttf`

Comment: FYI, you need to use @ notation, akin to Twitter, to ensure that replies to comments get picked up by the person you are trying to direct them towards. If by "I don't see it", you mean that the asset is not in your APK... that would be fairly strange. You can try cleaning and rebuilding the project (both found in the Build menu) and see if it shows up then.

Comment: @CommonsWare I rebuilt the project, and I can now see the font in the apk file, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: OK, that's even stranger. Try a full uninstall of the app from the device or emulator that you are testing on, then run it from the IDE again. If it crashes, double-check to see if it is the exact same error, as sometimes you might crash in a similar place for different reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did all of that, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Well, I am out of ideas. You can take a peek at [my book example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Fonts/FontSampler) and see if there's something obviously different between what I have and what you have.

Answer (score 2):

add assets folder in this path : `src/main/assets/font`

and use this code :

```
    Typeface typrface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/iranian_sans");

Text.setTypeface(typrface);
```

**Update**

ِDont Forget , you must copy `ttf` format of font in font folder

Comment: I'm still getting the same error when I make those changes.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what is different between your code and the question's code, and how that difference explains the crash.

Comment: @JamesRettie you sure copy font in font folder?

Comment: this is worked for me but I had to add the font file extension (.ttf) so it would be like this:                                                                                           
 Typeface typrface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/iranian_sans.ttf");

Answer (score -1):

It should be look like this when you want to give a TextView a different font :)

```
private TextView yourtext;

yourtext= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_textview);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/magorian_font.ttf");
    yourtext.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what is different between your code and the question's code, and how that difference explains the crash.